# Set Safari to open PDF files in Preview by default

Tags: safari, preview

I hope I didn't miss, but I haven't found any answer for this question in the community.
I only found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60322/understand-open-in-browser-vs-open-in-preview-for-pdf-files) answer, but it describes how to do so when accessing PDF files from the file system, not via links when browsing Safari.

Can I set Safari to open PDF files in Preview by default? (instead of opening it in a new browser tab)

The closest behavior I get is when I ask to *download* the file, Safari is set to immediately open it in Preview. However what I would like to achieve is that instead of haveing to load it first in the browser and press on download (or alternatively having to right-click and chose "Download Linked File") I would be able to simply click on the link of the PDF and automatically open it in Preview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's no mechanism for opening a link directly into Preview that I know of.

However, once the PDF is being viewed in Safari, you can open it in Preview by clicking on the third-from-left icon in the floating menu that appears when you mouse over an area at the bottom of the Safari window.

[image]

Some PDFs may download rather than display in the browser, but that's an issue at the server-side, rather than something you can configure at your end.